# Database diagnostic information on dashDB

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I am trying to load some data into a table in my dashDB database but hit an error message. Can I download db2diag.log from the dashDB console to find out what has happened?

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][10335][10366][4.18.60] Invalid operation: Connection is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003 Data loading failed.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Hi Jeff, that is the point of the question, to find out where I can retrieve db2diag.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff said, you can't access the logs of this DBaaS as it is shared resource. You will need to debug from your applications side. Are you maybe having a contingency problem with passing around the connection handle? Can you share your code?

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1205_ramachandra/1205_ramachandra.html

Details about enabling database tracing in Liberty:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.iseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jdbc_trace.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-3-11-0-5-3-1&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Since DashDB is a service, you don't have access to the logs that you normally would have access to.